# C: Matching a single space in a scanf

Tags: c

I just want to force a scanf to read a single space and then store the rest of the string until a comma is found in a variable. I cannot do it like this:

```
char content[100];
fscanf(f, " %[^,\n],", content);
```

because I don't want `content` to be set if there is a pending `'\n'`. 
Is there a way to scape the whitespace?

The workaround I've found so far:

```
char space;
fscanf(f, "%1[^\n]%[^,\n],", &space, content);
```

Sorry for the silly question and thank you in advance.

Comment: Your example code does not match up with your words.  You say a single *space*, but you seem to be trying to match a *newline*, instead.  You say you want to scan up to a semicolon (`;`), but you appear to be trying to scan up to a comma (`,`).

Comment: I am not matching the newline, i am trying to avoid exactly that. But you are right about the comma I already corrected that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm supposing that the code you presented expresses your intent better than your words, which don't correspond on the details.  Inasmuchas you say ...

> The workaround I've found so far:
>
> ```
> char space;
> fscanf(f, "%1[^\n]%[^,\n],", &space, content);
> ```

... I conclude that that code seems to you to do what you want, and I infer that you designate it a "workaround" instead of a wholly satisfactory solution on account of the need for the `space` variable to be involved.

Indeed, it's worse than that: whenever `scanf()` successfully matches the first field, it invokes undefined behavior by overrunning the bounds of `space`.  That happens because the `[` field descriptor matches nonempty *strings*, which have a terminator after their content.  But the good news is that getting rid of the need for the extra variable, which you seem to want to do anyway, will solve that problem, too.

The easiest way to do that would be to apply the assignment-suppression modifier (`*`) to the corresponding field descriptor:

```
fscanf(f, "%*1[^\n]%[^,\n],", content);
```

Do be sure to check the return value to determine whether anything was assigned to `content`.  It will be `1` if a non-empty string was matched and assigned to `content` (after matching but not assigning the leading newline), `-1` if the file `f` was initially positioned at its end or if an I/O error occurs, or `0` if a matching failure occurs before assigning `content`.

**Update**:

As @chux observed, the `scanf` format above does nothing to protect against overrunning the bounds of `content` in the event that the corresponding data is wider than it can accommodate.  Since you're declaring it as an array of 100 `char`, it can accommodate up to 99 characters plus a terminator, which you can ensure is not overrun like so:

```
fscanf(f, "%*1[^\n]%99[^,\n],", content);
```

That leaves you with the possibility that scanning stops before either a newline or a comma is seen, however, and the return value will not help you distinguish that case from a wholly successful scan.  In that event, the *next* scan will yield a matching failure (supposing that the same format is used).  There is more than one way to address that, but you might consider omitting the trailing comma from your format, and instead checking for a comma and consuming it separately via a call to `fgetc()`.

Comment: Suggest encouraging a width limit like `"%*1[^\n]%99[^,\n]," to avoid a `gets()` like vulnerability.

Comment: Thank you! I hadn't realised about the problem with space. And yes, I am using the value fscanf returns.

Comment: It's a workaround as it doesn't do what I want to do: escape a whitespace. In my specific case this works, but it is not a general solution that answers my question.

Answer (score 0):

And you have to use `fscanf()` because...?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

size_t myScan (
    const char * string,
    char * outBuffer,
    size_t outBufferMax
) {
    // No string
    if (!string) return 0;
    // First char not a space
    if (string[0] != ' ') return 0;
    // Find semicolon
    size_t size = 0;
    while (string[size + 1] != 0 && string[size + 1] != ';') size++;
    // Doesn't fit into buffer!
    if (size > outBufferMax) return 0;

    memcpy(outBuffer, &string[1], size);
    return size;
}


int main ( ) {
    size_t size = 0;
    char content[100] = { 0 };
    char * test = " Hello World; Test Test; Foobar!";

    size = myScan(test, content, sizeof(content));
    printf("###%.*s###\n", (int)size, content);

    size = myScan(&test[6], content, sizeof(content));
    printf("###%.*s###\n", (int)size, content);

    size = myScan(&test[13], content, sizeof(content));
    printf("###%.*s###\n", (int)size, content);

    size = myScan(&test[24], content, sizeof(content));
    printf("###%.*s###\n", (int)size, content);

    // No position with a space in front!
    size = myScan(&test[22], content, sizeof(content));
    printf("###%.*s###\n", (int)size, content);


    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
###Hello World###
###World###
###Test Test###
###Foobar!###
######
```

Comment: Because it is a snippet for zero-experience people and I prefer to keep it simple.

Comment: @nessa.gp I've been writing C code and working on C projects for maybe two decades and I never wrote or even saw that `fscan()` syntax you posted in the question. So how is that "simple" and for people with "zero-experience", if not even C veterans know that syntax? And how can something be simple if you must come here and ask for help because you cannot even figure out the correct syntax on your own? Sorry, but this seems illogical to me.

Comment: I have little experience with C. I just wanted to learn if there was a way of doing it. I was surprised that if you have a character with a special meaning, there weren't a way to block that behaviour and have just the original character, something similar to % and %% but with the whitespace.